# jQuery date sorting li div  browsers problems 

Tags: jquery, sorting, date, html, html-lists

Edit: 2

```
var elems = $("#D li").toArray();
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var adate = new Date($(a).find('div.dateDiv').text());
    var bdate = new Date($(b).find('div.dateDiv').text());
    return adate > bdate ? -1 : 1;
});
$("#D").html(elems);


<div id="D">
    <li>1<div class="dateDiv">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div><div>df</div></li> 
    <li>2 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div><div>df</div></li> 
    <li> 3 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div><div>ab</div></li> 
    <li>4 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div><div>a</div></li>

     <li>1<div class="dateDiv">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div></li>
   <li>2 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div></li>
  <li> 3 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div></li>
   <li>4 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div></li>


      <li>1<div class="dateDiv">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div></li>
   <li>2 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div></li>
  <li> 3 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div></li>
   <li>4 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div></li>


      <li>1<div class="dateDiv">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div></li>
   <li>2 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div></li>
  <li> 3 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div></li>
   <li>4 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div></li>
</div>​
```

i try it many times 
some problem with Firefox browser or IE or safari it's work only with opera and chrome , 
any one help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: to sort the li's: http://jsfiddle.net/katylava/dsNCX/13/

```
var elems = $("#D li").toArray();
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var adate = new Date($(a).find('div.dateDiv').text());
    var bdate = new Date($(b).find('div.dateDiv').text());
    return adate > bdate ? -1 : 1;
});
$("#D").html(elems);
```

*^^^final solution comes from @MerlynMorgan-Graham's deleted answer, not me*

**Edit**: the previous solution does not work in FF because it doesn't like the date format. So replace the space with a 'T'. However, this still does not work in Safari. http://jsfiddle.net/dsNCX/17/

```
var elems = $("#D li").toArray();
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    var adate = new Date($(a).find('div.dateDiv').text().replace(' ', 'T'));
    var bdate = new Date($(b).find('div.dateDiv').text().replace(' ', 'T'));
    return adate > bdate ? -1 : 1;
});
$("#D").html(elems);
```

Comment: Why toArray, what is the difference?

Comment: I think you're right, it doesn't make a difference. @engineer had it right, it works with makeArray too: http://jsfiddle.net/katylava/dsNCX/3/

Comment: that's not problem  i need to sort li Content by div Content date

Comment: Sorry, I mean your final sample doesn't work.  `toArray` does work.  The sorting is still broken tho.  See my answer for why.

Comment: If you look at it here: http://jsfiddle.net/katylava/dsNCX/6/ -- you can see it is sorting the dates properly (reverse chronologically).

Comment: @katylavallee: No, it's not.  I'm using chrome, and it doesn't work.  Maybe the `sort` function just isn't an option due to cross browser compatibility issues?  Just got a similar comment under my answer I posted

Comment: nm, I fail at reading comprehension.  I thought they were going to be ascending and just looked at the first two elements when I said you were wrong, lol :)  +1

Comment: Aha... no worries... I often fail at reading comprehension as well.

Comment: thanks good , but it there many divs as   <div id="D">
   <li>1<div class="dateDiv">2012-04-15 10:25:45</div><div>df</div></li>
   <li>2 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-10 19:41:08</div><div>df</div></li>
  <li> 3 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-20 07:00:10</div><div>ab/div></li>
   <li>4 <div class="dateDiv">2012-04-12 16:45:50</div><div>a</div></li>
</div>

Comment: I just updated it to show you how to loop over multiple divs.

Comment: Oh, you just have to say div.dateDiv instead. I updated it above.

Comment: it's stop work with many li please see it http://jsfiddle.net/dsNCX/10/  please help

Comment: well, now we know what @MerlynMorgan-Graham was talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/katylava/dsNCX/13/

Comment: can i ask you to hidden datetime after end from display

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't know what you mean.

Comment: hidden div.dateDiv from display

Comment: some problem with Firefox browser or IE or safari  it's work only with opera and chrome , any one help ?

Comment: @MichaelAtef Ok, debugging this I found that FF does not like the date format. I assume the same is true for Safari. I was able to fix it for FF by replacing the space in the date with a 'T', but that didn't help Safari. I suggest you post a new question asking what the proper cross-browser date format is for passing to `new Date()`.

Comment: thanks  so much , my news question   link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677730/what-the-proper-cross-browser-date-format-is-for-passing-to-new-date

Answer (score 3):

Sorting works correctly, just change `"#d"` to `"#D"`:

```
$("#D").html(elems);
```

Or change `id="D"` to `id="d"` in your markup.

```
<div id="d">
```

**UPDATE:** Sorting with `li` elements:

```
var elems = $.makeArray($("#D > li"));
elems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return new Date($('.dateDiv',a).text()) < new Date($('.dateDiv',b).text());
});
$("#D").html(elems);​
```

Comment: that's not problem  i need to sort li Content by div Content date